# Disable TS created printers when using Citrix ICA

Tags: citrix, windows-terminal-services

We've having some issues with printing from Citrix ICA from a certain piece of software. We're new to this but the person trying to print has had an older version of Citrix installed a few years ago and made some notes. In particular this:

*"TS autocreated client printers must be disabled in the TS setup for the software to work because it requires fixed printer names."*

I'm having trouble locating this particular option in the ICA client. My limited understanding of Citrix is that it's a different protocol to TS and so the TS printers shouldn't be mapped when using the ICA client?

Or does the ICA client pull through any TS created printers from the client on connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "**Citrix connection configuration tool**", you can prevent the client printers to be mounted by editing the ica connection --> clients settings --> uncheck "**Connect client printers at logon**".

There's the same configuration option in the rdp connection, you can configure it from the same tool.

The connection configuration tool can be accessed from the citrix server, in the administration tool menu, or by using the ICA toolbar.

Comment: Almost!

With your suggestion in hand I've found that it's actually in tscc.msc and in the ICA-rdp connection properties. 

Untick the 'Use connection settings from User settings' box and then untick 'connect client printers at logon'

Thanks!